# Subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}\ast \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-product

I want to see $\mathbb{Z}\ast\mathbb{Z}$ has a subgroup of index 4 which is not normal and I want to calculate the rank of this subgroup.

One way is to classify all the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}\ast\mathbb{Z}$. However, I want to know if there is easier way to see this.

Comment: How is composition defined here?

Comment: Do you mean $$\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z?$$ Because $\Bbb Z\ast\Bbb Z$ means something completely different.

Comment: @Shaun I mean $\mathbb{Z}\ast\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @Shaun The question is tagged "free product" so in this case  Z * Z means free product

Comment: I know that now, @DavidLui; I put that tag there after the clarification.

Comment: @Shaun Thank you!

Comment: You will have an interesting job classifying all subgroups of the free product ...

Comment: You say "I want to calculate the rank of this subgroup", but do you have reasons to believe that all examples will have the same rank?

Comment: ${\mathbb Z}*{\mathbb Z}$ is just the free group of rank $2$. You can find a non-normal subgroup of index $4$ (for example) as the image of a non-normal subgroup of index $4$ in the dihecral group of order $8$. It is freee of rank $5$ by the Schreier formula.

Comment: To extend Derek's comment: The *Schreier index formula* states that in the free group of rank $n$, a subgroup of finite index $k$ has rank precisely $1+k(n-1)$. This generalises to other groups via *Euler characteristic*: If $G$ has Euler characteristic $\chi(G)$ (which may or may not be defined) and $H$ is a finite index subgroup, then $\chi(H)$ is defined and we have $\chi(H)=\chi(G)[G:H]$. (This implies the Schreier index formula as $\chi(F_n)=1-n$ for $F_n$ free of rank $n$.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Somewhat interestingly, many results about free products are proved *geometrically*, and if I'm being honest, this technique is so useful I'm not familiar with purely algebraic ways to do what you're asking.
As such, this answer is going to rely on some [Algebraic Topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_topology), which you may have to take on faith depending on your background.

The idea is based on the following observations/theorems:

- $\mathbb{Z} \ast \mathbb{Z}$ is the
  [fundamental group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_group)
  of a wedge of $2$ circles.
- Subgroups of a fundamental group are in bijective correspondence with
  [covering spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space)
  of the underlying space.
- The subgroups of index $n$ are in bijection with the $n$-sheeted covering spaces.
- The normal subgroups are in bijection with the "maximally symmetric" covering spaces.

So, to find a non-normal subgroup of index $4$, we want to find a covering of the wedge of $2$ circles with $4$ sheets that *isn't* symmetric.

The wedge of $2$ circles looks like this:

[image: wedge of 2 circles]

(the loops $a$ and $b$ correspond to the generators of $\mathbb{Z} \ast \mathbb{Z}$)

We want a covering space (for our purposes, another graph) which has $4$ loops corresponding to $a$ and $4$ loops corresponding to $b$ (that gives $4$-sheetedness). We *also* want to know that some (labelled) edges cannot be taken to some other edges (of the same label) by a graph automorphism. This is what is meant by "not maximally symmetric" (formally, we want to know the group of (labelled) graph automorphisms isn't transitive).

I would draw one, but Hatcher actually provides an example on page 58 of his Algebraic Topology book (which is freely available [online](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/ATpage.html)):

[image: A covering space]

Figuring out exactly how we get this subgroup from this graph, or why this graph works, are the fundamentals of an algebraic topology class, so I won't try to describe what's going on in any detail. The quick version is

- There are $4$ edges labelled $a$ and $4$ edges labelled $b$. So this is a $4$-sheeted covering, and its fundamental group has index $4$ in $\mathbb{Z} \ast \mathbb{Z}$.
- If we start at the thick point and we follow $ab$, we get back where we started. However, if we look at the bottom right point instead, then $ab$ takes us to the top left point (so we *don't* get back where we started). This witnesses the "not maximally symmetric"ness that we need to show that the subgroup we get isn't normal.

So the subgroup that we get (which, loosely, corresponds to looking at all the ways to get from the thick point to itself):

$$\langle a^2, b^4, ab, ba^2b^{-1}, bab^{-2} \rangle$$

is non-normal of index $4$. As desired.

---

**Edit:** I totally forgot you also want the rank.

You might suspect this subgroup is of rank $5$, seeing as that's how many generators are listed. That suspicion is correct, as shown by another geometric fact:

The rank of a group that you get in this way is $1 - \chi$ where $\chi$ is the [euler characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic) of the graph. Here $\chi = -4$ is the number of vertices minus the number of edges, so the rank is

$$1 - \chi = 1 - (-4) = 5.$$

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: You can also do it by writing down a transitive action of $F_2$ on a set with $4$ elements whose stabilizers are distinct (this is equivalent to the stabilizer of a given point not being normal). This doesn't require any explicit covering space theory although it is nice to have covering spaces available.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan -- oooh, that's clever. I knew there had to be a more direct algebraic approach. Thanks ^_^